# How do you make an output that has a image in the center, and paragraphs and headings near the image to the right?

Tags: html, css

My code is like this:

```css
div {
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div id="unknowing">
  <img src="" height="200" width="350">
</div>
<div id="house">
  <h1>Ancient Rome</h1>
</div>
<div id="puzzle">
  <p>Ancient Rome was a great civilization, that along with Ancient Greece, contributed to many things in the modern world, like architecture, numbers, letters, and government.</p>
</div>
```

Unfortunately, I only got Ancient Rome below the image, but I want the heading and paragraph next to the image in the center. I tried to display the image as inline, but that didn't work because the image went to the left, I tried to use float but it didn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

just move the h1 tag into the div #unknowing

Comment: Add more style to the answer using the editor. It looks plain, try to use the code button to type code elements

Answer (score 0):

You can change the wrapper element of your content like this

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div>
    <div id="unknowing">
      <img src="" height="200" width="350">
    </div>
    <div id="house">
      <h1>Ancient Rome</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="puzzle">
      <p>Ancient Rome was a great civilization, that along with Ancient Greece, contributed to many things in the modern world, like architecture, numbers, letters, and government.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <style>
    body {
      display: flex;
    }

    body>div {
      width: 80%;
      margin: auto;
    }

    img {
      float: left;
      margin-right: 10px;
    }
  </style>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This layout with the text wrapping around the image is one of the only use cases left for the `float` property. I generally stay away from it since most modern layouts can generally be made with just flex and grid. I suppose using it for what its meant for is okay.